# Sony SmartWatch - override power button and double tap functionality

Tags: java, android, sony-smartwatch

I am using the control and sensor api from the Sony SmartExtension SDK, while reading in the data from accelerometer if the power button or the screen is double tapped with two fingers i lose connection to the accelerometer feed. Is there any way to detect these events and override native behaviour?

Comment: There is no way to override double tap or hardware button on Sony Smartwatch 1 since they help with basic navigation and hardware reset. This is an inherent behavior of the watch to save battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to override double tap or hardware button on Sony Smartwatch 1 since they help with basic navigation and hardware reset. This is an inherent behavior of the watch to save battery.